# Typescript route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Typescript.
I want to add custom parameter in route like "name"

```
<Route name="News" path="news" component={News} />
```

I try extend IRouteProps:

```
declare module 'react-router' {
  namespace ReactRouter {
    export interface IRouteProps {
      name?: string;
    }
  }
}
```

But it don't work.